# How to check if a Java ResourceBundle is loadable, without loading it?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I would like to check the existence of a ResourceBundle without actually loading it.

Typically, I'm using Guice, and at initialization time, I want to check the existence, while at execution time, I want to load it. If the bundle doesn't exist, I want an early report of the inexistence of the RB.

If it was possible to get the ResourceBundle.Control instance used for a specific ResourceBundle, I would have no problem getting the basic information to build the actual resource name (using toBundleName() and toResourceName()), but it is not the case at that level.

**Edit:**

Ok, I found the way to do it. I'll create a ResourceBundle.Control that is extensible (using a custome addFormat(String, Class)) to store all the bundle formats, then use another method of my own to check all possible file names for a specific locale (using Class.getResource as indicated here below).

Coding speaking:

```
class MyControl extends ResourceBundle.Control {
  private Map<String,Class<? extends ResourceBundle>> formats = new LinkedHashMap();
  public void addFormat(String format,Class<? extends ResourceBundle> rbType) {
    formats.put(format, rbType);
  }
  public boolean resourceBundleExists(ClassLoader loader, String baseName, Locale locale) {
    for (String format: formats.keySet()) {
      // for (loop on locale hierarchy) {
        if (loader.getResource(toResourceName(toBundleName(baseName, locale), format)) != null) {
          return true;
        }
      // }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the default bundle must exists you can do:

```
Class.getResource("/my/path/to/bundle.properties")
```

and it will return an URL to the file or null if it doesn't exists.

Of course use the correct class or classloader if you have many.

**EDIT:** if you have resources as classes you have to check also

```
Class.getResource("/my/path/to/bundle.class")
```

In Java 6 you can store resource bundles in XML. I don't know how ResourceBundle class lookups this resource, but I bet it's in the same way.

Comment: Rule: bundle "a.b.c" is resource "/a/b/c.properties" (default file)

Comment: The problem of this one is that I suppose that I have only properties files. I might as well have XML-based properties or classes.

Comment: I give a plus for the Class.getResource(), but with my previous comment I don't get the full answer to my question.

Comment: Understood. I didn't know bundles in XML or classes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can load the bundles, thus making your checks, and then call `ResourceBundle.clearCache()` so that they are loaded again next time.

This happens once (at initialization time), and it isn't such a heavy operation, so it won't be a problem.

Or you can simply try to find whether a resource is present on the classpath. For example the fallback .properties file, or the properties file for your default locale.

Finally, after having a look at the code for `ResourceBundle.Control`, you have the option to do what they do in the `newBundle()` method.

Comment: I certainly don't want to load twice the bundle. I would like to perform the check for early failure, so not spend the loading time in the initialization time.

Comment: why do you worry so much about that loading time? it happens once, and, well, loading a bundle isn't the most expensive operation.

Comment: Ok, in fact, there is the preinitialization time, the initialization time and the run time. I develop an API over Guice that needs to fast fail and any IO is time-consuming so that would become "not-so-fast fail". Performing one IO check is acceptable like in the other answer, but not one full load, with the properties loading/parsing, etc.

Short answer: it's part of my prerequisites.

Comment: that's still strange for me. applications are even not supposed to be started that often.

Comment: I understand your concern. I had the same when I planned the project, but the extensibility of the project explains the request.

By the way, it is not a J2EE application: only J2SE one.

Comment: anyway, check my update for looking at the source of the newBundle method

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe

```
ResourceBundle bundle;
public PropertiesExist() {
    String propsFile = "log4j";
    String propsPath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();
    File f = new File(propsPath, propsFile + ".properties");
    if(!f.exists()){
        System.out.println("File not found!!!!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(propsFile);
    System.out.println(bundle.getString("log4j.rootLogger"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     new PropertiesExist();         
}
```

This will look for the logging file, log4.properties, if not found program will exit