# Java JUnitCore check if bundle exists

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, bundle, exists

I am working on an Eclipse plugin where I want to run programmatically JUnitTest with the JUnitCore class. But I also want to check, if the right bundles are existing in the users IDE. So, if the user doesn't have the bundle `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core`, I don't want to insert a specific class in my project (which runs these tests with JUnitCore).

How can I make this?

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055799/how-to-check-if-a-java-resourcebundle-is-loadable-without-loading-it) out?  It may help.  [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) class may help too.

Comment: Isn't this answer specific for the ResourceBundle? I did not know this bundle until now. In which way this helps me? None of them help me (or I don't understand them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core");
```

to find the bundle / plugin, `null` will be returned if the bundle is not installed.

You can also check the bundle is active with:

```
if (bundle.getState() == Bundle.ACTIVE)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will immediately try this out and tell if it's working. For test purposes, I should remove this bundle from my IDE. How is this possible?

Comment: You could try looking in the `Plug-in Registry` and disabling the plug-in in the context menu (you need to enable advanced options for this). I'm not sure if this will work or not! It may return the bundle but with a different state.

Comment: Ok, I set the plugin to disabled and restarted my plugin. It could successfully checked that the bundle is not installed. Thus, your solution worked great! Thanks a lot :)!!!